# JDBC + MYSQL Communications link failure

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I definitely doing something wrong or I missed something but cant figure out what is that. I install XAMPP Apache/MYSQL. I connect locally and everything working fine. I try to make a step farther and get remote access to DB.

PROBLEMS

1. When I type myip/xampp in browser I see only "**The connection was reset**" but for everyone else is OK? (Xampp welcome page)
2. Cant connect via JDBC `error com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure` when before was working and change only hostname.

Here is code.

```
public DBConnect(String whichDataBase){
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"+whichDataBase+"?characterEncoding=UTF-8","monty","some_pass");
        st = con.createStatement();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error "+e);}
}
```

On database status tab its looks like its "connect?" (see host but command=`sleep` and getting error in java as above). But when I using VPN its connecting and working fine? o_O

Things I've done

- port forward 80 and 3306 on router (tested on http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/)
- changed `socket = "TCP/IP"` in `my.ini`
- comment out `#enable-named-pipe` and `#skip-networking`
- `bind-address="0.0.0.0"` (check also `127.0.0.1`)
- database user got ALL PRIVILEGES and GRANT on `localhost` and `%`

I'm a beginner so thanks for any help!

EDIT:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1036)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:338)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2232)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2265)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2064)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:790)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:395)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at DBConnect.<init>(DBConnect.java:17)
at Poro.actionPerformed(Poro.java:297)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireActionEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.contentsChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractListModel.fireContentsChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel.setSelectedItem(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel.addElement(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.addItem(Unknown Source)
at Poro.<init>(Poro.java:231)
at Poro.main(Poro.java:287)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:213)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:297)
... 24 more
```

Comment: Show the whole exception.

Comment: _But when I using VPN its connecting and working fine?_

Is the database accessible directly from your network otherwise or do you have to use the VPN?

Comment: @Jens this is whole exception? xD and i've been using VPN on other laptop to check if i can connect

Comment: @Michael No it is not. use e.printStacktrace()

Comment: Hi @Michael, have you magened to solve it? I an encoutnering the same problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it in this way:

```
public class MysqlConnect {

    static String template = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/%s?useEncoding=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&user=%s&password=%s";

    public void connect(String database, String user, String password) {

        Connection conn = null;

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(String.format(template, database, user, password));
            //...
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

So call `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance()` and add `username` and `password` to you connection string.

Check also this: [Connecting to MySQL Using the JDBC](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html)

Comment: Change on your way. Unfortunately nothing happen still same error.

Comment: @Michael can you access your database via console. Are you sure mysql database is running

Comment: Yes I can connect. db running

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I have tried in this way (modifying **[dit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1614378/dit)**'s answer code) and it worked for me:

```
public class SqlConnection {
    static String template = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/%s?useEncoding=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&user=%s&password=%s";

    public static Connection dbConnector() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(String.format(template, <database-name>, <username>, "password"));
            System.out.println("Connected succesfully");
            return connection;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: You have to modify *database-name*, *username* and *password* in *DriverManager.getConnection* method.
Finally, you can call:

```
SqlConnection.dbConnector();
```

Now, I can see "Connected successfully".